# ES6 rest parameter not working with babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, variadic-functions, transpiler

I am using an ES6 rest parameter in the simplest possible way:

```
function func(a, ...b) {
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i += 2) {
    console.log(b[i], b[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

I've installed `babel-preset-es2015`, and my `.babelrc` file simply has:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Strangely, the resulting output is:

```
"use strict";

function func(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
    console.log(arguments[i], arguments[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

I filed a bug at https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7000, but I'm extremely concerned since this is the second time I've had really basic ES6 transpile incorrectly using Babel 6. Is my setup broken? Is Babel 6 documented somewhere as unstable/alpha? Or is this highly popular module really just that bad? Are there any alternate ES6 transpilers out there written with compiler-grade rigor and comprehensive test suites that would be safe to use?

Comment: It looks like something may be wrong with your setup. I ran babel through your example code and got [an output different from yours](https://gist.github.com/leoetlino/0edf49ae631951132069). I have es2015 and stage-1 as presets, but having stage-1 or not shouldn't matter.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using `6.3.13` (the latest); are you using the latest? Or maybe `stage-1` is necessary?

Comment: babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13, babel-cli@6.4.0, babel-core@6.4.0. The rest module is also 6.3.13 (babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread@6.3.13 according to npm list).

Comment: Maybe stage-2 is necessary. babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread is a dependency for stage-2 (stage-1 includes stage-2).

Comment: [es2015 does not contain the rest module](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/); that's probably why it didn't work correctly. However, I do think that's a bug, because it should fail early instead of generating incorrect, broken code.

Comment: It does contain `transform-es2015-parameters`, which mentions rest parameters: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I discovered.

A preset is a collection of transform plugins, all versioned with `^`. It seems that as these transform versions are bumped, new version of the preset are not published. It's not a good source for a curated set of plugins that are known to work together. So in my case, despite the fact that I had the latest `babel-preset-es2015`, and a new version of that didn't exist, it didn't mean I had all the latest plugins as well.

Forcing newer versions of the constituent plugins fixed the issue for me. The preset version tells you nothing useful apparently. If you don't have a direct dependency on the plugins themselves, the only way to force them to update is to force a reinstall of the preset.

Comment: Are you using npm v3 or v2? npm v3 seems more reliable for updating dependencies.

Comment: NPM v3, but it doesn't really relate. Unless something explicitly gives a dependency version that conflicts with what's currently installed, neither version on NPM will update the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The transform you're looking for is http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/, which is not part of `babel-preset-es2015`, but is part of `babel-preset-stage-2`, or you can install it by itself.

Comment: `babel-preset-es2015` includes `transform-es2015-parameters`, which does the rest spread in parameters. It turned out that an older version of `transform-es2015-parameters` was to blame for the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same ES6 rest parameter problem as Jacob had. I followed yaycmyk's advice and did `npm install babel-preset-stage-2` and then changed my gulp file from
 `pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))` to 
 `pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2'] }))` and on my merry way I went.